# While loop to save csv files with conditional name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'd like to make a `while` / `for` loop in python to save dataframes into csv files.

The files should be named something like: Day1, Day2, Day3...Day90

First i determine for the n-th day, how large of a sample I should draw, based on a forecast.

Then the sample is drawn from the population (`Orders_df`), and should be written into a csv file

```
Period = list(range(0,90))
Period

for item in Period:
Percentage = (forecast['yhat'].iloc[Period]) / (forecast['yhat'].max())
Samplesize = round( Orders_df.lat.count() / 90 * Percentage)
Orders_df.sample(Samplesize).to_csv('Day'&Period&'.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you could do something to this effect

```
for item in Period:
     Orders_df.sample(Samplesize).to_csv(f'{item}<whatever you wanna call the file>.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: It seems to work, however i get this error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:'

Should have something to do with my filepath, but can't figure out how to solve it

Comment: so you might need to change your code to be this `variable = 'Documents'
path = rf'C:\Users\Computer\{variable}\YourFile.csv'` because the f string will allow you to insert variables into a string function and the r will allow you to have a raw file. r strings are usually used when manipulating file paths. This is because it makes it where you don't have to do \\ everytime you need to do a \ in your code

Comment: It still doesn't work.. i'll try to add the variable a dataframe. If i'm correct pandas dataframes can have more than 2 dimensions...

Afther this i will continue processing the data, so no need to save csv files allready